# Avoid USB/Serial adapter port change in Windows enviroment

Tags: windows, usb, serial-port, adapter

I would like to know if there is some way to "fix" a serial port to common usb/serial adapters. Many times I saw that changing usb port of adapter it takes a new serial port number. It happends also if I plug the adapter after the Windows startup.
I tried with Prolific adapters and also many printer-virtual-com software.

Obiouvsly this is big trouble because I have to setup every time the correct com port.

Answer (score 1):

This is a quick trick, maybe it will help:

http://www.dopsys.com/appnotes/Assigning%20COM%20Port%20Numbers%20to%20the%20Serial%20Ports%20of%20a%20USB-to-Serial%20Adapter.pdf

*Note: This is a download link.  Clicking on it will immediately download an 8 page PDF file.*

Comment: Welcome to Super User. People are security conscious and get concerned when clicking a link immediately downloads an unknown file.  It's a good idea to include a notice on live download links.  BTW, if it takes 8 pages to explain, I'm not sure I'd categorize it as a "quick trick".  In general, it is better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and reference.  If the link breaks, your answer would have no value.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.